# ChoiceBox has a 50 options how can I limit the height of drop down list. Java Scenebuilder

Tags: java, scenebuilder

An image of my program demo, I would like to have it only show 10 or so items at a time to choose from. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

[image of my program issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNMgo.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot limit the height of the drop down list of a `ChoiceBox`.

The [documentation of `ChoiceBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html) explicitly states:

> The ChoiceBox is used for presenting the user with a relatively small set of predefined choices from which they may choose.

50 possible choices doesn't fit into the category of "relatively small set".

You could use a [`ComboBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) instead of the `ChoiceBox`. With a `ComboBox` you can limit the number of visible items.

Comment: Will do thanks so much!